# Recyclerview click item 1 abrir activity 1, click item 2 abrir activity 2

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

```
public class ListAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ListAdapter.MyViewHolder> implements View.OnClickListener {

    private List<Categoria> categoriaList;
    private Context Context;


    public interface ItemClickListener {
        void onItemClick(View view, int position);
    }


    public ListAdapter(List<Categoria> list) {
        this.categoriaList = list;


    }

    @NonNull
    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

        View itemLista = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.listagem, parent, false   );

        Context = itemLista.getContext();

        itemLista.setOnClickListener(this);

        return new MyViewHolder(itemLista);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

    //getLayoutPosition não esta funcionando

    switch (getLayoutPosition()){
            case 0:

                Context.startActivity(new Intent(Context, Flash3ep_t1.class));

                break;

            case 1:
                Context.startActivity(new Intent(Context, Splash.class));

                break;
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, int position) {

        Categoria categoria = categoriaList.get(position);
        holder.titulo.setText(categoria.getTitulo());
        holder.line.animate();



    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return categoriaList.size();
    }

    public class MyViewHolder extends  RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        TextView titulo;
        View line;



        public MyViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);


            titulo = itemView.findViewById(R.id.title);
            line = itemView.findViewById(R.id.line);

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Coloquei o seu `OnClick` dentro da `MyViewHolder` e utilize o `getAdapterPosition`, como no exemplo abaixo:

```
public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    TextView titulo;
    View line;

    public MyViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);


        titulo = itemView.findViewById(R.id.title);
        line = itemView.findViewById(R.id.line);

        itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                switch (getAdapterPosition()) {
                    case 0:
                        Context.startActivity(new Intent(Context, Flash3ep_t1.class));
                        break;
                    case 1:
                        Context.startActivity(new Intent(Context, Splash.class));
                        break;
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: meu único problema está sendo no getAdapterPosition() que esta dando erro pedindo pra implementar um método etc. irmão desde já obrigado pela ajuda!. sobre o getAdapterPosition sabe o que há ?

Comment: @WesleyFrost então você está fazendo algo errado, pois se você esta na classe que extends de RecyclerView.ViewHolder, ele já possui o método getAdapterPosition()

Comment: @WesleyFrost na verdade o erro não é só getAdapterPosition, você só esta com o onClick nesse local pois no seu Adapter você esta implementando o View.OnClickListener, porem quem é clicado não é o Adapter e sim o item da Recycle, no se seu caso o MyViewHolder, o onClick deve estar lá e lá você terá acesso ao getAdapterPosition() poís ele é um metodo da RecyclerView.ViewHolder, que é quem o seu MyViewHolder  extende.